# Send notification when app is background

Tags: android

I'm sending notification while my app is in background. The notification is sending when app is background but when i click the notification and open the app then the app is crashing. I need to send notification when the app is only on background and i have been doing this for iBeacon development.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 
         notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            ;


           new ForegroundCheckTask().execute();

    }


    class ForegroundCheckTask extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Boolean> {

          @Override
          protected Boolean doInBackground(Context... params) {

              postNotificationUBCity("Entered region");
            final Context context = params[0].getApplicationContext();

            return isAppOnForeground(context);


          }

          private boolean isAppOnForeground(Context context) {
            ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
            if (appProcesses == null) {
              return false;
            }
            final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
            for (RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses) {
              if (appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND && appProcess.processName.equals(packageName)) {
                return true;
              }
            }
            return false;
          }
        }
```

Log :

```
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008): Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008):    at com.example.beacon.MainActivity$ForegroundCheckTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:450)
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008):    at com.example.beacon.MainActivity$ForegroundCheckTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-19 18:31:01.300: E/AndroidRuntime(13008):    ... 4 more
```

Comment: "The app is crashing". So where is the Logcat?

Comment: Please share your log of app crash.

Comment: Please check the Logcat..

Comment: add PostNotification's code, and I can't understand you are calling this asyncTask in onCreate() then how it is getting called in 'background' ?

Comment: @Darpan: where should i call asyncTask?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't go with AsyncTask for this purpose.

If you want to send a notification when your application is in background mode, try using this code on your `onPause()` method:

```
/**
* Checks if the application is being sent in the background (i.e behind
* another application's Activity).
* 
* @param context the context
* @return <code>true</code> if another application will be above this one.
*/
public static boolean isApplicationSentToBackground(final Context context) {
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)    context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
 List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
 if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
  ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
  if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
    return true;
  }
 }

 return false;
}
```

Add the proper notification:

```
private void addNotification(Context context, String message) {

 int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
 long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
 String appname = context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name);
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
 .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

 Notification notification;
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
 new Intent(context, myactivity.class), 0);


 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
 context);
 notification = builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
 .setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(appname).setWhen(0)
 .setAutoCancel(true).setContentTitle(appname)
 .setContentText(message).build();

 notificationManager.notify(0 , notification);

 }
```

Don't forget to include the permission on your AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
```

That should work.